# Using Redis and MongoDB together, best to store each session in Redis and update the DB at session end?

Tags: database, mongodb, server, redis

I found an article [here](https://redislabs.com/blog/the-top-3-game-changing-redis-use-cases/) which explains the top 3 uses of Redis. For my minecraft network I am going to have to include session management, player profiles, leaderboards etc. which Redis seems perfect for.
MongoDB seems perfect for storing player data as a Json format (previously used MySQL) (EDIT: I also read [this](http://www.sarahmei.com/blog/2013/11/11/why-you-should-never-use-mongodb/comment-page-1/) article here and it may have scared me from using MongoDB).

Originally, I planned to have a system where:

A player logs into the network -> their data is fetched from MongoDB and stored into Redis -> the player joins a server on the network -> their data is fetched from Redis and stored inside a profile wrapper object -> the player leaves the server to join another server -> their data is saved into Redis on the old server -> their data is downloaded from Redis in the new server -> the player leaves the entire network -> their data is stored into MongoDB and removed from Redis.

I am going to create a ProfileSnapshot class which contains a snapshot of the profile when it was loaded, so that if the data inside hasn't changed when the player moves onto a new server, the data isn't saved.

I am wondering if it is possible that the data save to Redis is slower than the data load from Redis on the new server - so that the data downloaded wouldn't be the real data.

Secondly, is it efficient loading the MongoDB player profile into Redis, should I even use Redis for this? Or should I just load player data from MongoDB each time a player moves from server to server? Is Redis useful in this case? Would MongoDB be fast enough to load the data and save the data constantly? I'm expecting to have maybe 400 players on the network at once.

Are there any other designs that I could use to have a network where data is accessible for all players, where the data is stored in MongoDB / Redis? The player data needs to be on the server the player is on at all times, and a player can change server at any time.

Extra info:

Redis only stores the profiles of online players.

Redis and MongoDB are commonly used for Minecraft Networks (possibly irrelevant, but just ensures that my ideas may be acceptable).

Speed is key.

Data needs to be available to my website too, so flatfile isn't an option. etc.